# How to make a loop that counts up in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to make a program that looks like it is downloading something (for entertainment purposes.) I've been trying to get to count from 0 KB to 3.27 KB in increments of 0.01. I want it to look like it goes from 0/3.27 KB to 3.27/3.27 KB

How can I create a loop that will actually be able to do this?

Comment: So you want to edit a line in a terminal emulator? If so, please [edit] to say so.

Comment: You could use a `while` loop that includes a line which looks like `x += .01`, but that still leaves unanswered the question if you are trying to do this by repeatedly changing a single line in the terminal or if you want the prints to be on successive lines.

Comment: Are you able to "create a loop" **at all**? What happened when you tried to write code for this task? (For example: what do you think should happen, each time through the loop? What is the rule that will tell you when the loop should stop?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was not able to write a loop at all, as I couldn't find a way to make it work correctly.

Comment: I mean, can you write a loop that does any other task? Do you understand what the syntax is for a loop? Have you seen `for` and `while` in your tutorial material? Or how exactly are you learning Python?

Comment: I have been able to write a loop that does other tasks, yes. I have been learning Python through books and courses online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic counter that I believe will do what you want.

```
def count_bytes(count_to_this):
    count = 0
    while count < count_to_this:
        format_float = "{:.2f}".format(count)
        print(f"{format_float}KB/{count_to_this}KB")
        count += 0.01
  
count_bytes(3.27)
```

if you want to add a delay for each iteration you could something like

```
import time

def count_bytes(count_to_this):
    count = 0
    while count < count_to_this:
        time.sleep(2)
        format_float = "{:.2f}".format(count)
        print(f"{format_float}KB/{count_to_this}KB")
        count += 0.01

count_bytes(3.27)
```

If you wanted add a degree of randomness to the timer, you could use `random.randint()`

Comment: Except for implementing a \r carriage return into it, this code is working exactly as I wanted it to be. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem! in the future I would recommend including any code you have written pertaining to your question. Makes it possible for someone to point out where you might be hitting snags as well as why your code is not working as intended. If you are just getting started with python, Python Principles is a great web based resource for learning the basic logic and syntax.

Comment: I will include some code in my questions from now on, and I will definitely check out Python Principles. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @KeiranHaas - if the post did help you, you should check it and mark it as accepted answer.